# How do i change value of a variable inside a loop

Tags: c++, loops

I try to check the format of the input value with the while loop.

If the input is wrong, I want to get back and ask the user to give a new input. But inside the loops, `retVal` keep being `1`.

How do I change the value of `retVal` through `SetCode()` function?
This is the SetCode() function

```
bool Grocery::SetCode(long _barcode)
    {
        bool retVal=true;
        if(_barcode>10000000||_barcode<0) retVal=false;
        else barcode=_barcode;
        return retVal;
    }
```

```
int retVal=0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<index; ++i)
{
 cout<<"Enter the name of the grocery item: ";
 cin>>_name;
 grocery[i].SetName(_name);
 cout<<"Enter the barcode of the grocery item (up to 7 digits): ";
 cin>>_barcode;
 grocery[i].SetCode(_barcode);
 while(retVal==1)
 {
     cout<<"Invalid Value"<<endl;
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore();
     
     cout<<"Enter the barcode of the grocery item: ";
     cin>>_barcode;
     grocery[i].SetCode(_barcode);
 }
}
```

Comment: Whatever the `SetCode` function is, it has no knowledge whatsoever about the `retVal` variable. So you need to either give that function a return value or add some other code to modify `retVal`

Comment: With the code you've shown, your claim that `retVal` is always 1 is impossible.  The value of `retVal` is 0 and it is never modified.

Comment: can we see the source code of SetCode please

Comment: What does the name "retval" mean to you? Think about it, and the solution should be obvious.

Comment: i have added the setcode() function, thank you

Comment: You should probably validate `_barcode` before applying it to `SetCode`, unless `SetCode` valudates it; in which case you clearly need to inspect _its_ return value to determine the result.  Also if you used a do-while loop you would not need the duplicate inlut code inside and outside the loop.  Also all symbols prefixed with an underscore are _reserved_ by the implementations namespace.  You should avoid creating such symbols in your own code.

Comment: Oh FFS.  Clearly then `retVal = grocery[i].SetCode(_barcode);`.  How would you expect `retVal` to be assigned otherwise!?  The _local_ symbol of the same name in another function _is not_ the _same_ symbol.

Comment: Based on how it is used (and how it probably should be used) `int retVal=0;` should be `bool retVal=false;`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change a local variable with a function, that function must accept that variable as an argument. Assuming `_barcode` is an integer, and `SetCode` function just check if `_barcode` is less than 8 digits, then you can change the `SetCode` to:

```cpp
void Grocery::SetCode(int barcode, int& retVal)
{
    if(barcode >= 0 && barcode < 10'000'000)
    {
        this->barcode = barcode;
        retVal = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = 1;
    }
}
```

And call `SetCode` like:

```cpp
grocery[i].SetCode(_barcode, retVal);
```

---

An alternative is get rid of the `retVal`, and return an `bool` from `SetCode`, so you can directly use the result of `SetCode` for the while loop condition:

```cpp
bool Grocery::SetCode(int barcode)
{
    if(barcode >= 0 && barcode < 10'000'000)
    {
        this->barcode = barcode;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in the main, you can do something like:

```cpp
cin >> _barcode;
while(!grocery[i].SetCode(_barcode))    // the while loop would run if SetCode returns false
{
    cout << "Invalid Value" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the barcode of the grocery item: ";
    cin >> _barcode;                    // after getting user input, it will run SetCode again, and if it fails again the loop will run again
}
```

Comment: Some armour on the `cin >> _barcode;` is recommended to to detect IO errors.